# Swift 4: How to asynchronously use URLSessionDataTask but have the requests be in a timed queue?

Tags: swift, multithreading, asynchronous, networking, swift4

Basically I have some JSON data that I wish to retrieve from a bunch of URL's (all from the same host), however I can only request this data roughly every 2 seconds at minimum and only one at a time or I'll be "time banned" from the server. As you'll see below; while URLSession is very quick it also gets me time banned almost instantly when I have around 700 urls to get through.

How would I go about creating a queue in URLSession (if its functionality supports it) and while having it work asynchronously to my main thread; have it work serially on its own thread and only attempt each item in the queue after 2 seconds have past since it finished the previous request?

```
for url in urls {
    get(url: url)
}


func get(url: URL) {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

        if let error = error {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            return
        }
        let data = data!

        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("Server Error")
            }
            return
        }
        if response.mimeType == "application/json" {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String: Any]
                if json["success"] as! Bool == true {
                    if let count = json["total_count"] as? Int {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.itemsCount.append(count)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Recursion solves this best

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

// Let asynchronous code run
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

func fetch(urls: [URL]) {

    guard urls.count > 0 else {
        print("Queue finished")
        return
    }

    var pendingURLs = urls
    let currentUrl = pendingURLs.removeFirst()

    print("\(pendingURLs.count)")

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: currentUrl, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        print("task completed")
        if let _ = error {
            print("error received")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                fetch(urls: pendingURLs)
            }
            return
        }

        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            print("server error received")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                fetch(urls: pendingURLs)
            }
            return
        }
        if response.mimeType == "application/json" {
            print("json data parsed")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                fetch(urls: pendingURLs)
            }
        }else {
            print("unknown data")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                fetch(urls: pendingURLs)
            }
        }
    })

    //start execution after two seconds
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { (timer) in
        print("resume called")
        task.resume()
    }
}

var urls = [URL]()
for _ in 0..<100 {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://google.com") {
        urls.append(url)
    }
}

fetch(urls:urls)
```

Comment: Used this answer successfully.  Is there a practical limit for how deep the stack can handle?

Comment: Since we are using async to spawn the new task, this will not act as stack. Hence, you are free to use as many as the array can handle.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to perform recursive call:

1. Imagine you have array with your urls.
2. In place where you initially perform for loop with, replace it with single call `get(url:)`.
   `self.get(urls[0])`
3. Then add this line at the and of response closure right after `self.itemsCount.append(count)`:

   ```
   self.urls.removeFirst()
   Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { (_) in
   self.get(url: urls[0])
   }
   ```

Comment: It looks like Ankit Kumar Gupta ran with your idea a few hours later.  Although your answer doesn't flesh out the details, it was picked up and was valuable. +1

Answer (score 0):

Make `DispatchQueue` to run your code on threads. You don't need to do this work on Main Thread. So,

```
// make serial queue
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "getData")

// for delay
func wait(seconds: Double, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) { completion() }
}

// usage
for url in urls {
  wait(seconds: 2.0) {
      self.get(url: url) { (itemCount) in
         // update UI related to itemCount
      }
  }
}
```

By the way, Your `get(url: url)` function is not that great.

```
func get(url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping ([Int]) -> Void) {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            /* Don't need to use main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            */
            return
        }
        let data = data!

        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            print("Server Error")
            /* Don't need to use main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("Server Error")
                }
            */
            return
        }
        if response.mimeType == "application/json" {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String: Any]
                if json["success"] as! Bool == true {
                    if let count = json["total_count"] as? Int {

                        self.itemsCount.append(count)

                        // append all data that you need and pass it to completion closure
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completionHandler(self.itemsCount)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

I would recommend you to learn concept of `GCD`(for thread) and `escaping closure`(for completion handler).

- GCD: https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1
- Escaping Closure: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID546

Comment: What if there will be slow connection and an actual time between calls for server may vary, because `get` returns immediately.

Comment: @DenisLitvin In that case, some of requests will fail and error message will be printed. If you want to handle that, you need to set timeout setting from urlsession data task.

Comment: Nope, that IP will be banned due to server restrictions. As said in the question

Comment: This won't wait 2 seconds between each request because `get` runs asynchronously (i.e. returns immediately), so in effect it will start all the requests two seconds after it hits the `for` loop.