# Swift 4: Creating an asynchronous serial queue with 2 seconds wait after each job

Tags: swift, multithreading, asynchronous, queue, swift4

Have had trouble visualising this...

I think I need 2 threads and am not sure how to implement them.

I need to have a 2 second delay minimum in between each network retrieval requests after it has been completed.

Main Thread:

UIButton pressed --> Function adds a network retrieval request to a serial queue --> UILoop continues...

Network Thread:

Checks queue for next request --> Begins request --> Finishes request --> Waits 2 seconds --> Checks queue for next request --> Begins request --> Finishes request --> Waits 2 seconds --> Checks queue for next request --> No request --> Checks queue for next request... or Ends loop until recalled.

```
var networkQueue = [NetworkRequest]()
var networkQueueActive = false

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    networkQueue.append(NetworkRequest(UIButton))
    if networkQueueActive == false {
        networkRetrieveFromQueue() // need to asynchronously call this DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO THIS
    }
}

func networkRetrieveFromQueue() {
    networkQueueActive = true
    while !networkQueue.isEmpty {
        let request = networkQueue.remove(at: 0)
        // synchronous network data retrieval on this thread KNOW HOW TO DO THIS
        // do something with the data retrieved KNOW HOW TO DO THIS
        // wait 2 seconds DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO THIS
    }
    networkQueueActive = false
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a repost of [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694633/swift-4-how-to-asynchronously-use-urlsessiondatatask-but-have-the-requests-be-i)?

Comment: Yes. I've updated it; is this not the way to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have

```
var networkQueue = [NetworkRequest]()
var networkQueueActive = false
```

Then, your `networkRetrieveFromQueue` should:

- check to see if the queue is empty;
- if not, grab the first item in the queue;
- initiate the asynchronous request; and
- in the completion handler of that asynchronous request, call `networkRetrieveFromQueue` again after 2 seconds

Thus

```
func startQueue() {
    if networkQueueActive { return }

    networkQueueActive = true
    processNext()
}

// if queue not empty, grab first item, perform request, and call itself
// 2 seconds after prior one finishes

func processNext() {
    if networkQueue.isEmpty {
        networkQueueActive = false
        return
    }

    let request = networkQueue.removeFirst()

    get(request: request) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.processNext()
        }
    }
}
```

Where your "process request" might look like:

```
// perform asynchronous network request, with completion handler that is 
// called when its done

func get(request: NetworkRequest, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request.request) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error ?? "Unknown error")
            completionHandler()
            return
        }

        // process successful response here

        // when done, call completion handler

        completionHandler()
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Now, I don't know what your `NetworkRequest` looks like, but this illustrates the basic idea of how to recursively call a function in the completion handler of some asynchronous method.

Comment: I notice in this answer that each request is its own thread (or 2 threads with URLSession) that on completion it waits 2 seconds and then creates a new thread while closing its own; is this preferential to having one thread that freezes for 2 seconds before looping? Not that I even know how to delay a normal loop in Swift... I really like this answer though!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're talking about. `URLSession` runs its completion handlers on a serial queue (so that's one), and `asyncAfter` is going to run `processNext` on the main thread (so that's a second one). So there are really only two queues involved, the main queue and the `URLSession` serial queue. (Note, you're not guaranteed which worker threads the serial queues uses, so don't worry about that. Just make sure to not instantiate a new `URLSession` for each request: But I (and you) used the shared session, so that shouldn't be an issue.)

Comment: Sorry I misread the `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`; so this means that when the UI of my application has its next downtime it will run `processNext()` after a minimum of 2 seconds'?. As for creating data tasks with `URLSession` I was under the impression that each were separate asynchronous network calls but you are saying that no matter how many I create they will be serial queued separately to the other queue we have created ourselves just obviously without the 2 second pause? Still struggling a bit with this multithreading stuff.

Comment: Yes, `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` will run the dispatched block on the main queue after 2 seconds. By scheduling this on the main queue, we avoid all sorts of problems associated with mulit-threaded code. We're dealing with only two "threads", the main thread and what is used by the `URLSession` completion handlers. I think the above is a nice concise way of doing what you needed, without introducing any synchronous network code or other complexity. We recursively tell GCD to do something in 2 seconds on the main queue, and everything is nice and tidy.